# Bootstrap responsive navbar toggle button not working

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, wordpress-theming

I'm working on a custom theme for WordPress and I'm currently on the responsive navbar. It is showing me the toggle-icon but when I click it nothing happens.

I'm working with the last version of bootstrap, downloaded directly from the website...

I have jquery loaded on the header:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/eltecnofilo/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1' id='jquery-core-js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/eltecnofilo/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=3.3.2' id='jquery-migrate-js'></script>
```

and on the footer the bootstrap files:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/eltecnofilo/wp-content/themes/ElTecnofilo/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js?ver=5.0.0' id='bootstrap-js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/eltecnofilo/wp-content/themes/ElTecnofilo/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.esm.js?ver=5.0.0' id='bootstrap-esm-js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/eltecnofilo/wp-content/themes/ElTecnofilo/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.js?ver=5.0.0' id='bootstrap-bundle-js'></script>
```

And this is my code for the navbar

```
<div class="row full-width black-bg">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-target aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse-target">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <?php
                    $getMenu = wp_get_nav_menu_items( 'menu principal'); // Where menu1 can be ID, slug or title
                    foreach($getMenu as $item){
                        echo '<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="' . $item->url . '">' . $item->title . '</a></li>';
                    }
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: I think that if you want the fully interactive widgets that bootstrap provides, you should include popper.js as well, and I'm not seeing it in your script files.

Comment: @PedroUzcátegui popper.js ??? don't know it, but in theory it should work without that correct?

Comment: in the answer I link the docs, and it says that you need to include popper as well to get `many` of the bootstrap components working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### BOOTSTRAP DOCUMENTATION

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/

> Many of our components require the use of JavaScript to function.
> Specifically, they require our own JavaScript plugins and Popper.
> Place one of following s near the end of your pages, right
> before the closing  tag, to enable them.

Remember that Bootstrap depends on Jquery and Popper.js for their dynamic functionality.

I do not see Popper.js in your scripts files, try including it.

https://popper.js.org/